# PyLint --init-hook via subprocess.run() not working (maybe escape problems)

Tags: python, pylint

I do run `pylint` in unittests using `subprocess.run()`.
I need to use `--init-hook=` feature of `pylint` to encourage it to find my modules.

I do run this on shell (bash) and it works as expected:

```
pylint qttools.py --disable=all --enable=E0401 --init-hook="from pathlib import Path; import sys;sys.path.append('./../common');"
```

No error E0401 detected.

Now I try to replicate that but using `subprocess.run()`.

```
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import run
>>> cmd = ['pylint', 'qttools.py', '--disable=all', '--enable=E0401']
>>> cmd.append('--init-hook="from pathlib import Path; import sys;sys.path.append(\'./../common\');"')
>>> run(cmd)
************* Module qttools
qttools.py:48:0: E0401: Unable to import 'snapshots' (import-error)
qttools.py:49:0: E0401: Unable to import 'tools' (import-error)
qttools.py:50:0: E0401: Unable to import 'logger' (import-error)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 9.55/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, -0.45)

CompletedProcess(args=['pylint', 'qttools.py', '--disable=all', '--enable=E0401', '--init-hook="from pathlib import Path; import sys;sys.path.append(\'./../common\');"'], returncode=2)
```

My assumption is that escaping the `'` around the `common` path is a problem. I tried some alternatives (switching `'` and `"`; building the string via `+` operator). The result keeps the same.

Any ideas?

I am aware that I wouldn't need to use `--init-hook` or `sys.path` hacks like this if I created a correct and valid Python package out of this repo. I am working on this, but it is 15 year old Python code.

Comment: You could also use the pylint's API directly: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development_guide/api/pylint.html#recover-the-result-in-a-stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The problem was that I surrounded the value of `--init-hook` by `"`.

```
>>> cmd.append('--init-hook="from pathlib import Path; import ..."')
                            ^                                    ^
```

Removing it works fine.

```
>>> cmd.append('--init-hook=from pathlib import Path; import sys;sys.path.append(\'./../common\');')
```